# How to add notification sounds using Xam.Plugin.Notifier plugin in Xamarin Form?

Tags: xamarin.forms, notifications, localnotification

I am using [Xam.Plugin.Notifier](https://github.com/edsnider/localnotificationsplugin) in my Xamarin Form project. I am able to get the notification working by following the guide in the link above.

However, I wasn't able to find any resource or tutorial to guide how to set the sound when the notification is shown.

I am wishing may get some guide/clue how can I achieve that.

Comment: I don't think there's an inbuilt function in the notification plugin that takes sound as a parameter. You can simply play the sound at the time of notification.

Comment: that's a shame, without the sound capability, the notification seems useless as the users wouldn't be aware of the new notification. However, I appreciate your comment though.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about it. Have you tried debugging in some other device? Perhaps, it vibrates or makes a sound? If not, you can always play the sound before invoking this notification plugin method.

Comment: It will play the default notification sound of the device I'm pretty sure.

Comment: No, it did not play any sounds when receive local notification using the plugin. My solution is use DI, and schedule the notification in native codes.